# How do I create a new variable in R if it does not already exist?

Tags: r, dplyr, spread, tidytext

I am currently using tidytext in R to do some sentiment analysis. I'm using code extremely similar to the one listed at the vignette. This is the example given:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tidytext.html

```
library(tidyr)
bing <- get_sentiments("bing")

janeaustensentiment <- tidy_books %>%
  inner_join(bing) %>%
  count(book, index = line %/% 80, sentiment) %>%
  spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(sentiment = positive - negative)
```

I have adapted this to use on fairly short blocks of text, using the exact same inner_join %>% spread %>% mutate progression. The problem is that I have at least one block of text that is giving me problems. I think it is because it has no negative sentiment at all. This is the error message:

```
x object 'negative' not found
Input 'sentiment' is 'positive - negative'
```

I think there should be a way around this--to create a variable if it doesn't exist--but I cannot get it to work. I am thinking of something like:

```
mutate(negative = 0) ifelse(exists())
```

But I cannot seem to figure out how it would work. Does anyone have an idea of how to create a new variable if it does not exist, but not create it if it does? Or, alternately, if there's a solution to this within tidytext itself.

EDIT June 17th: I just checked what happens after "spread", and indeed there is no "negative" variable/column. So it is possible that if I can create a new variable--if and only if it does not yet exist--with values of "0" I can proceed.

Comment: Can you check the column names after `- tidy_books %>%
  inner_join(bing) %>%
  count(book, index = line %/% 80, sentiment) %>%
  spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>% colnames`

Comment: Can you please provide an input output example? Thank you!

Comment: What does `get_sentiments` do? What does it return?

Comment: If you just create a txt file that says "happy happy happy happy" that should recreate the problem. get_sentiments just grabs the sentiment dictionary.

Comment: @akrun I checked manually what happens. Here's what happens: At "spread" it creates one column (positive) instead of two (positive and negative).

Answer (score 1):

Without example data, it's a little hard to say for sure, but I think you want to try using `complete()` from [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr). You can specify which columns you want to make sure you have all combinations of, and what value to use to fill in any missing data. For example, let's say that document 2 is missing its negative sentiment:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sentiments <- tibble(
  document    = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3),
  sentiment   = c("positive", "positive", "positive", "negative", "negative"),
  n           = c(5, 8, 2, 9, 3)
)

sentiments
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   document sentiment     n
#>      <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1        1 positive      5
#> 2        2 positive      8
#> 3        3 positive      2
#> 4        1 negative      9
#> 5        3 negative      3

sentiments %>%
  complete(document, sentiment, fill = list(n = 0))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   document sentiment     n
#>      <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1        1 negative      9
#> 2        1 positive      5
#> 3        2 negative      0
#> 4        2 positive      8
#> 5        3 negative      3
#> 6        3 positive      2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

If you use an approach like this with your documents, I expect you will be able to avoid the problem you are experiencing and can move on to `spread()` (or its more up-to-date cousin, [`pivot_wider()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html)).

Comment: I've been trying to use this and I can't figure it out. Where exactly do you suggest doing that? I don't think I've had a document list like that. I'm calculating it out within each document. I realize this is complicated without a reproducible example but if you did an analysis on something that just read "happy happy happy happy" there should be no instance of "negative" in the sentiment column.